# Woocommerce Tax not appearing while selecting Local Pickup as Delivery

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

While I am selecting Local Pickup as my delivery option, Tax is reflecting based on item total.
however, if I use Distance Rate the tax is getting calculated.

I wanted tax to be calculated while selecting Local Pickup.

Note: No tax will be calculated on the Shipping amounts.

[image]

[image]